# URLRewrite support for angular application hosted in Azure Blob Storage account

Tags: angular, azure-blob-storage, url-rewrite-module

I have a angular application hosted as IIS website with URLRewrite (https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite) module in an on-premise environement. This module provides rewriting capabilities based on rules for the requested URL address and the content of an HTTP request. Now I am trying to host the application using the Static website hosting available in Azure (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-static-website).

All the Rewrite rules are managed in the web.config file in the current on-premise solution. Also this application is using Akamai CDN for accelerating the content delivery.

Can anyone help me to know how to manage the URLRewrite module equivalent at Azure Blob Storage level.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [azure function proxy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-proxies) where your site is deployed. Here is for frontend you will have every url starting with `/api`.

```
{
    "$schema": "http://json.schemastore.org/proxies",
    "proxies": {
        "root": {
            "matchCondition": {
                "route": "/api/{*route}",
                "methods": [
                    "GET",
                    "HEAD"
                ]
            },
            "backendUri": "https://my-dot-net-server/{*route}": {
                //If you want to override any headers
            }
        }
   }
}
```

The above proxy will redirect your request to dotnet url and send the response. For more details, you could refer to this [article](https://dev.to/effectory/hosting-an-angular-app-as-a-static-website-with-azure-function-proxies-3m44) about making requests to Angular routes work.

Comment: Thanks @Joey Cai for your response. I would like to understand the real purpose of azure function proxy here. If I am deploying the angular app using the azure static site feature of the blob storage then in this case what is the use case of azure function proxy.  Any help on this is much appreciated

Comment: We have an Angular application, a storage account to hold our application files, and now we need to configure the Function Proxies to serve our content. Refer to this [article](https://peteskelly.com/angular-function-proxies/).